# I am not able to pass the newly generated multiple ids into next table. My script is

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my script:

```
DECLARE @id VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @id = '1344,1345'

DECLARE @Sid TABLE (Sid VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO person
OUTPUT inserted.personid INTO @sid 
    SELECT value id, 200, abc
    FROM [dbo].[fn_Split](@id, ',')

SELECT * FROM @sid 

INSERT INTO relatedperson
    SELECT value sid, 15527, '2019-11-04 02:20:00.000'
    FROM [dbo].[fn_Split](@Sid, ',')
```

I want to pass 2 generated person-ids to insert in the next table that is related person to generated 2 rows each with 1 person id.

Here is [fn_Split]

```
ALTER  FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split]
    (@id VARCHAR(MAX), @delimiter VARCHAR(20) = ' ')  
RETURNS @Strings TABLE  
                 (     
                     position INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,  
                     value VARCHAR(8000)    
                 )  
AS  
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @xml XML
    SET @XML = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' + REPLACE(@id, @delimiter, '</i><i>') + '</i>')

    INSERT INTO @Strings (value)
        SELECT row.value('.','VARCHAR(100)') as parsedValue 
        FROM @xml.nodes('/i') AS Records(row)

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: Using serialized datas goes against the purpose of using a RDBMS. Think about [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: What's the problem? and what's the tsql of `[dbo].[fn_Split]`?

Comment: Why are you using an ml-TVF to split the data? That's an awfully slow way to do it. If you're using SQL Server 2016+ use `STRING_SPLIT`, and if you're using something older I higher recommend looking up `DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD`. If not, at least change the above from an ml-TVF to a i-TVF.

Comment: What's the purpose of doing that? Well, you can use After Insert Trigger of sql server. Just write after insert trigger on the Person table and inside add new entry into RelatedPerson table, you will get it from INSERTED table. Please check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Sample data and desired results would certainly help me understand what you are trying to do.